# Sharepoint 2010 listview row color change

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

After creating a listview from VS2010 and adding it as a web part to sharepoint 2010, the rows have an alternating color which i do not want but cannot seem to change. I have tried putting in conditional formatting for columns and rows as well but it does not work!

I have tried changing the style in the .ascx file as well to :

```
<style type="text/css">
.style1
{
    width: 159px;
    height: 53px;
    background-color: White;
    text-align:left;
}
</style>
<img alt="" class="style1" 

<SharePoint:ListViewByQuery runat="server" ID="ProjectsListView" class ="style1" />
```

but nothing seems to work! Does anyone have a solution for this? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-alternating
{
    background-color: White;
}
</style>
```